# Adding an attribute to input children of hidden elements with jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, webforms

I'm trying to accomplish something with JQuery and I can't seem to get it to work. A lot of that has to do with me not being a JQuery guy, so I'm sure this is all wrong.

I have a very large form, with some conditionals to where certain form sections don't show up, depending on what radio button value is selected. So what I've done, is when a certain value is selected, it will add or remove a "hide-me" class to a div element, so all form fields inside don't show. The issue is, if I have some required, the form won't submit and you can't fill out a field that isn't visible. So what I want to do is when the form is submitted, it should first grab all child input elements within any div with the class of hide-me and set an attribute of disabled.

How can I accomplish this?

Here is some example code: http://codepen.io/amarit84/pen/KMgKRd

```
$('#test_form_id').submit(function() {
    $('.hide-me').children(":input").prop("disabled", true);
});
```

Comment: [It does work already](https://jsfiddle.net/bu7tjucv/), doesn't it?

Comment: not much experience in  jquery but since you have more then one input element, right? i think you are missing `.each()`

Comment: @Vijay The code OP's provided does already work without any additions.

Comment: @nicael, it doesn't work for me. Doesn't work on this sample codepen I put together, nor my real project. When you say it works, are you trying it, or just basing that off of the code you see and suspect it should work? Just curious.

Comment: U have not added jquery plugin in codepen

Comment: When you add or remove the "hide-me" class why don't you just remove all the 'required' attribute? with something like `$('{YOUR-PARENT-ELEMENT-SELECTOR-HERE}').find("*").removeProp("required");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put it outside your submit(), your example is not working so I added jquery on your codepen.

```
$('.hide-me').children(":input").prop("disabled", true);
$('#test_form_id').submit(function() {

});
```

It will always trigger to fill the form hidden because jquery code to disable hidden input is inside your submit(), the HTML5 validation is stopping you from triggering submit thats why your code to disable the hidden inputs wont execute.[codepen sample updated](http://codepen.io/nerfe/pen/aZmbrq)

Comment: Thanks. I guess what confuses me a little bit is how the form knows to run that first line of jquery? That's really the only reason I put it in the submit function to begin with.

Comment: It doesn't know. If outside a function, this first line will be executed onload.

Comment: I cant really expound on it and i dont really now much to explain on how codepen manage to read the first line, but usually i add $document.ready to ensure that it will run the scripts when page is ready. if you think my answer to you question is acceptable please accept as answer, thanks.  [jquery document ready](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.hide-me').children("input").attr("disabled", true);
```

**But**, since you do this `onsubmit`, I don't understand you try to do this. Page reloads anyway...

[Here's a Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/vy61dqqd/) with «modified» code.

Comment: I just updated the Fiddle in order to make your enable link to work.